# Can't find books to learn Romanian

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, physical-resources, romanian

I'm looking for books to learn Romanian. I have used searches such as "Romanian A1", "Romanian verbs", "Romanian vocabulary", but nothing. I mean, there were pages of course, but no books.

Comment: Could you please add which language(s) the learning materials should be in?

Comment: I can understand portuguese, english and italian.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following resources:

- *Discover Romanian: An Introduction to the Language and Culture* by Rodica Boţoman. 425 pages (textbook), a set of 10 audio CDs and a student workbook. Published by [Ohio State University Press](https://ohiostatepress.org/books/BookPages/BotomanDiscover.htm), 1995.
- *Colloquial Romanian: The Complete Course for Beginners* by Ramona Gönczöl and Dennis Deletant. Published [Routledge, 2012](https://www.routledge.com/Colloquial-Romanian-The-Complete-Course-for-Beginners/Gonczol-Deletant/p/book/9781138960176). 368 pages. ISBN 9781138960176.
- *Teach Yourself Romanian! - Romanian for the English Speaking World* by Eugenia Tanasescu. 240 pages, including a CD. Published by [Teora](http://www.teora.ro/cgi-bin/teora/romania/mbshop.cgi?database=04&action=view_product&productID=1374&category=). ISBN-13: 9789732013748.
- *Teach Yourself Complete Romanian* by Dennis Deletant and Yvonne Alexandrescu. 2011. McGraw-Hill Education, 2011. (Unfortunately, I couldn't find this book on the publisher's website.)

If you want books focusing specifically on Romanian grammar:

- *Romanian: An Essential Grammar* by Ramona Gönczöl. 240 pages. Second edition, to be published by [Routledge in December 2020](https://www.routledge.com/Romanian-An-Essential-Grammar/Gonczol/p/book/9781138230569). If you can't wait until December, get the [first edition from 2007](https://www.routledge.com/Romanian-An-Essential-Grammar/Gonczol-Gonczol/p/book/9780415338257).

Comment: Thank you, dear, it helps much!